# Positioning CSS in 3 columns

Tags: css, position, word-wrap

I am trying to create a 3-column web-layout with CSS. Currently I have the following:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
.container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px 0 0 220px;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
}
.lefter{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 450px;
  height:50%;
}
.righter{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 450px;
  height:50%;
}
section {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin-left: 450px;
  margin-right:450px;
  top:5px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="containter">
    This is the Container Class it takes up a certain portion of the HTML page 
    <div class="left" style="border:1px solid">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Taco Menu</li>
          <li>Draft List</li>
          <li>Hours</li>
          <li>Directions</li>
          <li>Contact 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="righter" style="border:1px solid">
        <ul>
          <li>Right1 </li>
          <li>Taco Menu</li>
          <li>Draft List</li>
          <li>Hours</li>
          <li>Directions</li>
          <li>Contact 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <section>
           Center Column
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently the output looks (similar to this layout) like this in a maximized window:

```
Home              Center Column     Right1
Taco Menu                           Taco Menu
Draft List                          Draft List
Hours                               Hours
Directions                          Directions
Contact                             Contact
```

Where there are three columns A-B-C, corresponding to the above like so:
      [A]               [B]              [C]

When you resize the browser, the following collapses, (and rearranges the columns):

```
Home                Right1            Cen
Taco Menu           Taco Menu         ter
Draft List          Draft List         Co
Hours               Hours             lumn
Directions          Directions
Contact             Contact
```

Rearranged as:
    [A]                   [C]             [B] | Where [B] Wraps its text.

What I am trying is for the column's B & C to maintain their relative sizes(i.e. no wrapping) and for the browser window to add a width scroll bar instead of wrapping the center column (B) and collapsing the right column (C) over the other two columns. For a sample website: http://help.gathercontent.com/developer-api/

To get this behavior, is it a function of the position attribute? Relative to the other elements on the page or is it another element attribute?

References:
http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not telling the section that contains the "center colum" text a width so there's no way it will known you wanted it to behave like that and stop wrapping. 
On the other hand, I would try a faster aproach which would be to write your html in order as it's supposed to be rendered, make them all sections or all divs, and give them a class i.e. "main-box" and set them to display:inline-block so they'll render one next to the other. With some nice margins you are avoiding to play with positioning that much.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the guy that advises you to make a responsive layout, side scroll is terrible UX. I am not entirely sure about what you are trying to achieve here, is it something like this?

```
    <HTML>
    <head>
    <style>
    .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    }
    .block {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-right: 1%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
    }

    .center-block {
    width: 58%;
    }

    .left-block,
    .right-block {
    width: 15%;
    }

    .block:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    }

    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    }
    .cf:after { clear: both; }
    .cf { *zoom: 1; }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container cf">
    <div class="block left-block">
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Taco Menu</li>
    <li>Draft List</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Directions</li>
    <li>Contact 1</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="block center-block">
    <p>Center Column</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block right-block">
    <ul>
    <li>Right1 </li>
    <li>Taco Menu</li>
    <li>Draft List</li>
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Directions</li>
    <li>Contact 2</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```